# Check For Duplicate Entries In An Array - Xcode/Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have the following array of arrays ::

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>aa</key>
        <string>2012-07-19 11:16:00</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>bb</key>
        <string>2012-07-19 11:16:02</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>cc</key>
        <string>2012-07-19 11:16:05</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

The name of this array is `abcd` and it is `NSMutable`.

I want to add a new `dict` element into this array, say with `key` value of `aa` and some other `string` value. I want to check if this new `key` value already exists as a `key` for some `dict` element. How can I do that ?? Can someone help me out ?? Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to store your data as a dictionary rather than an array of key-value pairs?

Comment: You mean you have an array of dictionaries, not an array of arrays.. can't you just insert the key-value pairs of all the dictionaries in your array into a single separate dictionary? Now your array of dictionaries has simply become a single dictionary, so you can check for an existent key, or update the value corresponding to a preexisting key simply by adding the key-value pair to the dictionary (if that's what you want). [If the order of the dictionaries in the array was important, you can keep track of that separately, and reconstruct your array of dictionaries again if need be]

Comment: I actually dont know what code to write .. I wud prefer having a single dictionary.. can you write some code into the answer .. I am new to objective C.

Comment: Take a look at [The Developer Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/collections/collections.html). Once you understand the difference between the collection classes and when to use one or the other, implementing will be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say **arr** is your `NSMutableArray` and **dictToBeAdded** is your dictionary to be added. And let **strKey** is the key for this dictionary :

```
for(int i=0;i<[arr count];i++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
    for(NSString *str in [dict allKeys])
    {
         if(![str isEqualToString:strKey])
             [arr addObject:dict];
    }
}
```

Comment: where should I declare `strKey` and how ? Thanks.

Comment: I have taken strKey just for reference. It is the key of the dictionary you want to have. eg if you are adding **vv** and its value, then **vv** is strKey.

Comment: No need to declare it. Just replace strKey by the string you are using as key.